# "Пороть горячку"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение выражения "пороть горячку" (то есть, излишне торопиться, суетиться).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Пороть горячку** - неодобр. Действовать с крайней поспешностью и неосмотрительностью. **Горячка** здесь - лихорадочность (намек на ненормальный, усиленный жар в лихорадке). Первоначально выражение относилось к тому, кто в состоянии повышенной нервозности спешил исправить брак (распороть неправильно сшитое) и окончательно портил вещь. (Историко-этимологический словарь "Русская фразеология" А.К.Бириха и др.)

Answer (score 1):

Я очень сомневаюсь в "портновской" этимологии.
Если горячка - неправильно сшитое, то его можно и нужно пороть.

Пороть в значении "делать бездумно", "ошибаться" известно и без горячки. Семантика та же, что и в портновскском значении (резать, делать дыру), но непосредственно с ним не связана. Поэтому предпологаю "естестенную" этимологию. Горячка - результат горячности, пороть - действовать в состоянии горячности.

Ещё одно объяснение - за горячку якобы пороли. Розгами. Но сомнительно.

Answer (score 0):

Пороть горячку это армейский термин 18 века, по сути тренировка военного состава, обучение оружию, ближнему бою холодным оружием, штыковая атака, рукопашному бою. Чио пороли? Помимо получаемых навыков, рвались маникены, на которых отрабатывались приёмы, содаты и офицеры тренировались и это было очень эмоционально горячо... Ибо Русская армия непобедима, Бог с нами, Слава Богу. ❤️